# Moving an item to the end of a double linked list in C

Tags: c, pointers, doubly-linked-list

I'd like to make a function that takes an item in a doubly linked list a move it to the end of its list. If you want to have a list of structs the struct needs to have a list_elem inside of it. Here it is.

```
    struct list_elem 
  {
    struct list_elem *prev;     /* Previous list element. */
    struct list_elem *next;     /* Next list element. */
  };
```

In the list there is a head and tail as well. In the provided code there is a swap() function that takes in two pointers to pointers for list_elem s but I'm a little confused on how I would use this to move a item in the list. Here is is.

```
static void
swap (struct list_elem **a, struct list_elem **b) 
{
  struct list_elem *t = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = t;
}
```

If i had a list like this `h -- 1 -- 2 -- 3 -- t` with h being its head and t being its tail I would like to make a function that you can give the struct list *l and the list_elem *e and convert it into this (this example i will move 1) `h -- 2 -- 3 -- 1 -- t`

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: if i had a list like this 

`h -- 1 -- 2 -- 3 -- t` 

with h being its head and t being its tail I would like to make a function that you can give the struct list *l and the list_elem *e and convert it into this (this example i will move 1)
`h -- 2 -- 3 -- 1 -- t`

Comment: Just keep swapping the element with its successor until it's the last one. A more efficient solution is simply to delete the element and insert it at the end of the list.

Comment: That `swap` function will result in nodes with mismatched `next`/`prev` pointers.

Answer (score 1):

There at least two general ways you could implement a move-to-the-end operation:

1. Excise the target node from the list, then append it at the end; OR
2. In a loop, as long as the target node is not the last, swap it with its successor.

The usual ways to implement either one of those would involve manipulating nodes' `prev` and `next` pointers, but note well that the `swap()` function presented in the question does not perform a *node* swap, but rather a *pointer* swap.  You can implement the node swap described in option (2) via the (pointer) `swap()` function presented, but it would be uglier, messier, and more error prone than working directly with the pointers involved.  (Your `swap()` would be more appropriate for use with an array of pointers than with a linked list.)

Other details are left as the exercise they are meant to be.

Comment: What would be the use-case for the O(n) (worst case) swap loop, when a constant time O(2) remove-insert approach is available (as well as easier to code)...?

Comment: @Myst, remove / insert is O(n) too if you don't initially have a pointer to the tail.  Or one could contrive an example where swaps are the only operation that can be performed, though such a situation is unlikely to arise in the real world.

Comment: True, `swap` is a valid approach in cases where we have a **singly** linked list without a known  `tail` pointer. However, OP asked about a **doubly** linked list. If there's no pointer to the head/tail, the swap feature will be an endless loop on that one...

Comment: @Myst, *doubly-linked* is not the same thing as *circular*.  The two characteristics are completely orthogonal.  You can absolutely have and work productively with a doubly-linked, non-circular linked list where you know the head but not the tail.

Comment: Guess I learned something new. I never had the use case for a non-circular doubly linked list, so I didn't realize they can be used without linking the tail to the head. Thanks for clarifying 